# Deleting commented lines in a text file using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am a `sed` novice.  I would like to use `sed` to delete commented lines in a text file.

In my series of text files, commented lines ***begin*** with either the `#` symbol or the `@` symbol (i.e., they are files originally intended for plotting in `xmgrace`).  Suppose I have the following sample file (called `sample.txt`):

> ```
> # Comment 1
> # Another comment
> # Yet another comment
> @ More comments
> @ Still more comments
> data1
> data2
>
> data3
> ```

I would like to use `sed` to modify `sample.txt`, in place, to obtain the following:

> ```
> data1
> data2
>
> data3
> ```

where there is a blank line between "`data2`" and "`data3`" in both versions of `sample.txt`.

With inspiration from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350223/sed-remove-and-empty-lines-with-one-sed-command), I came up with this series of (consecutive) commands:

```
sed -i 's/#.*$//' sample.txt
sed -i 's/@.*$//' sample.txt
```

which give this resulting file:

> ```
>     <blank line>
>     <blank line>
>     <blank line>
>     <blank line>
>     <blank line>
> data1
> data2
>
> data3
> ```

where `<blank line>` is just a blank line.  (I had to write it this way so that Stack Exchange would format the output correctly.)

The problem with the above is that the commented lines are only replaced with blank lines, not deleted altogether.

Another possibility of (consecutive) commands is:

```
sed -i 's/#.*$//' sample.txt
sed -i 's/@.*$//' sample.txt
sed -i '/^$/d' sample.txt
```

from which I obtain the following output:

> ```
> data1
> data2
> data3
> ```

The above is, however, also wrong because the blank line between "`data2`" and "`data3`" has not been preserved (I am incorrectly deleting all blank lines, indiscriminately).  How do I just delete the commented lines?

I am running Ubuntu Linux.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [sed delete command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30) (here assuming GNU `sed` as found on Ubuntu and other GNU systems).

```
 sed -i '/^[@#]/ d' sample.txt
```

If you need to account for leading space characters:

```
sed -i '/^\s*[@#]/ d' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '^[^@#]' < file.in > file.out
```

would get you the lines that start with any character but `@` and `#` so effectively remove the `#foo`, `@foo` lines but also the empty lines.

```
grep -v '^[@#]' < file.in > file.out
```

would preserve the empty lines. If you want consider lines that have blanks before the `@`, `#`:

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*[@#]' < file.in > file.out
```

And to also remove blank lines:

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]@#]' < file.in > file.out
```